# I have been trying to install various different extensions from Eclipse Marketplace, but they all fail

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

See the example below. Is there any resolution? I'm running the latest version of Eclipse (2022-09) and Java 17. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to install a plugin that is too old for the version of Eclipse you are using.

The missing dependency is for org.eclipse.core.runtime in the range 3.7.0 to 3.12.0.  That looks to be from about March 2017.  And according to the [plugin's page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bytecode-visualizer) in Marketplace, it only supports up to the Eclipse Mars (4.5) release.

You are using the Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25) release.

Solution: There isn't a good one.  Your options are:

- Downgrade to Eclipse Mars which requires Java 7 to run (**ouch!!**) and doesn't support Java 9+ code.
- Look for another way of visualizing bytecodes.
- Offer someone<sup>1</sup> *lots of money* to:

  - track down the latest source code for the plugin,
  - produce releases that are compatible with recent versions of Eclipse, and
  - make them available via the Marketplace.

---

<sup>1 - ... either the author, or someone else.  Hint: doubt that "Dr Garbage" is interested since he has allowed his domain name registration to expire.</sup>

Comment: _"Offer someone lots of money to: track down the latest source code for the plugin, ..."_ - lol: https://sourceforge.net/p/drgarbagetools/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/com.drgarbage.sourcecodevisualizer/

Comment: I know.  I found it myself.  But is that the **latest** source code?  Or just the lastest **publicly available** version?

Comment: But the idea that someone whose interest seems to be reverse engineering is going to pay someone to do some coding for them is kind of implausible.

Comment: Sure, it's the latest (see publishing date of the [update site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/drgarbagetools/files/eclipse/4.5/stable/) vs. source code history). The plugin is not about reverse engineering, not about decompiling, but about understanding bytecode. It's a nice open source project for which unfortunately nobody invests a weekend of time to make it work again with the current Eclipse.

Comment: Did I just see you volunteering @howlger?  Or offering money to pay someone else to do the work?  My point is that if the OP wants this desperately enough, he has a way or ways to make it happen.  And so does anyone else ... including you ... if you think this is a "nice" project.

Comment: If the OP is interested in the bytecode, which few Java developers really know about, then she is probably also smart enough to maintain the plugin (for missing Eclipse plugin skills, there are [nice tutorials](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipseplatform.html)). The only question is whether she or someone else wants to invest their time to do so. If help is needed, I am happy to help for free. I'm also open to get _"lots of money"_ to do all the work.

Comment: I will leave you guys to negotiate :-)

Comment: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Vq7csh83U4 .... :-) )